# winston logger: how do you suppress (drop) a log line based on some custom logic?

Tags: logging, winston

If I return an empty string from my custom formatter, it writes an empty string to the log file. I want it to log nothing at all, based on an inspection of the log `meta` object. I tried this:

```js
import { format } from 'winston';
const { printf } = format;
const myFormat = printf((info) => {
  const { level, message } = info;
  if (message !== 'blah')
    return `level=${level} msg="${message}"`;
  return ''; // ideally i don't want to the log line to be an empty string. I want this logline to be dropped entirely.
});
```

I thought we could return `false` in a log formatter to suppress the entire log line, but it seems this gives the error:

```
Argument of type '(info: TransformableInfo) => string | false' is not assignable to parameter of type '(info: TransformableInfo) => string'.
```

So it seems I have no choice but to return an empty string.
Is there a way in winston 3 to drop an entire log line based on some logic? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] According to the [Winston docs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#filtering-info-objects) and the TypeScript defs, the `printf()` function can only return a `string` as you've discovered. So let's leave that as it is and supply our own filtering function that conforms to the:

```
(info: TransformableInfo, opts?: any) => TransformableInfo | boolean
```

required shape of a `TransformFunction` and then `combine` them:

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';



  const suppressEmptyLogs = format((info: TransformableInfo, _: any) => {
    if (!info.message || info.message.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return info;
  });

  const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.combine(
      myFormat
      suppressEmptyLogs(),
    ),
  });
```

Now you should get the behaviour you want with each function just doing one thing well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I think my question was not clear; I'll try to update it. I don't mean that the log line is empty and I need to suppress it. I mean I have a valid log line, and based on the `meta` payload, i want to suppress it.